# Convert Timestamp as per TimeZone in java

Tags: java, java-8

I have a Timestamp object and a TimeZone object

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
TimeZone userTimeZone = preferenceService.getPreferredTimezone();
```

I want a function which modifies  **timestamp** as per the **userTimeZone** . The function should return **Timestamp**. Could someone help ?

Comment: >I want a function which modifies timestamp…< You don't. That's not necessary. The necessary localization will be done automatically when the correct time zone is used with it

Comment: Is that `java.sql.Timestamp`?

Comment: yes @rzwitserloot

Comment: What you're asking for is akin to saying that [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre#/media/File:US_National_Length_Meter.JPG) needs to be made a little longer as the majority of the staff of the International Bureau of Weights and Measure is now short-sighted

Answer (score 0):

Your question is non-sensical. A Timestamp instance represent an instant in time. It doesn't have timezone info and isn't a timezoned stamp.

Instead, when showing a Timestamp to a user, in the step of 'convert this computer-time-kept concept to something to show the user', you'd do the job there. You wouldn't do that by first 'converting the timestamp to this timezone', you'd either do that in one go, or better yet, get to the `java.time` package as fast as possible because all other time libraries (including those in almost all DB engines) are non-sensical.

In java.time terms, you'd get to a ZonedDateTime, and hten you can convert that to another zone, and from there, potentially via a LocalDateTime, to rendering it to the user.

Given that you said the function must return a Timestamp, the code that uses this method is broken, so fix it there.